# Adding dictionaries recursively in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following two functions which take two dictionaries and recursively add their values.

```
def recursive_dict_sum_helper(v1, d2, k):
    try: v2 = d2[k]
    except KeyError: return v1 #problem is here if key not found it just return value but what about rest of the keys which is in d2??

    if not v1: return v2
    # "add" two values: if they can be added with '+', then do so,
    # otherwise expect dictionaries and treat them appropriately.
    try:
        if type(v1) == list and type(v2) == list:
            v1.extend(v2)
            return list(set(v1))
        else:
            return v1 + v2
    except: return recursive_dict_sum(v1, v2)

def recursive_dict_sum(d1, d2):
    if len(d1) < len(d2):
        temp = d1
        d1 = d2
        d2 = temp
    # Recursively produce the new key-value pair for each
    # original key-value pair, and make a dict with the results.
    return dict(
        (k, recursive_dict_sum_helper(v, d2, k))
        for (k, v) in d1.items()
    )
```

If I give the following input then the output is fine which I am expecting:

```
a = {'abc': {'missing': 1, 'modified': 0, 'additional': 2}}
b = {'abc': {'missing': 1, 'modified': 1, 'additional': 2}}

mn = recursive_dict_sum(a, b)

output: mn = {'abc': {'missing': 2, 'modified': 1, 'additional': 4}}
```

but if the input is:

```
a = {'abc': {'missing': 1, 'modified': 0, 'additional': 2}}
b = {'cde': {'missing': 1, 'modified': 1, 'additional': 2}}

output: {'abc': {'missing': 1, 'modified': 0, 'additional': 2}} #which is wrong
```

If there is no key found in the 2nd dictionary it returns key value from first dictionary. So it is operating on one dictionary items, what about the rest of keys in the second dictionary? How can I update the above script so that the output would be:

```
output: {'abc': {'missing': 1, 'modified': 0, 'additional': 2}, 'cde': {'missing': 1, 'modified': 1, 'additional': 2}}
```

Comment: Minor note: swapping values can be done with `d1, d2 = d2, d1` in Python, no need for a `temp` variable.

Comment: what your try/except clause want to catch ?

Comment: try/except is catching keyerror, recursive function is calling on d1.items() it means that there is no guarantee that that key would always be in d2, if it is there then update the values.

Comment: no, it is catching **everything** (that includes the unimaginable). that was my point. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand right what you want to do, all of it could be achieved with the following code:

```
def dict_sum(d1, d2):
    if d1 is None: return d2
    if d2 is None: return d1
    if isinstance(d1, list) and isinstance(d2, list):
        return list(set(d1 + d2))
    try:
        return d1 + d2
    except TypeError:
        # assume d1 and d2 are dictionaries
        keys = set(d1.iterkeys()) | set(d2.iterkeys())
        return dict((key, dict_sum(d1.get(key), d2.get(key))) for key in keys)
```

`dict_sum(a, b)` will give the desired result.

Just note that it will raise an `AttributeError` if called with incompatible types such as

```
dict_sum({'a': 1}, 2)
```

**Edit** to treat lists specially (create list with unique elements).

Comment: there are three things which can be present in dictionary lists, integers and dictionary. it just not integers which i need to add.

Comment: `a = {'abc': {'missing': [123, 456], 'modified': 0, 'additional': 2}}` `b = {'abc': {'missing': [789], 'modified': 0, 'additional': 2}}` then output would be `{'missing': [123, 456, 789], 'modified': 0, 'additional': 4}}`

Comment: I edited the code to treat lists in a special way. The output should be `{'abc': {'additional': 4, 'modified': 0, 'missing': [456, 123, 789]}}`, shouldn't it?

Comment: yes you are right, i forget to write key. i am testing your code and so far it is working great..

Answer (score 3):

Made in one monster-generator as you seem to like it :)

```
def recursive_dict_sum(d1, d2):
    return dict((k, ((d1[k] if k in d1 else d2[k])
                       if k not in d1 or k not in d2
                      else (d1[k] + d2[k] if not isinstance(d1[k], dict)
                                        else recursive_dict_sum(d1[k], d2[k]))))
                for k in set(d1.keys() + d2.keys()))
```