# adding dict2 to dict1 in python

Tags: python, recursion

Say I have two nested dicts.

```
dict1 = {"good authors": {"john" : {}, "jack" : {}}, "average authors" : {"kim" : {}, "peter" : {}} }
```

then

```
dict2 = {"john" : {{"2008" : "book1"}, {"2009" : "book2"}}, "peter" : {{"2008" : "book3"}, {"2009" : "book4"}}}
```

How could I add dict2 to dict1 recursively?

The result should looks like:

```
{"good authors": {"john" : {{"2008" : "book1"}, {"2009" : "book2"}}, "jack" : {}}, "average authors" : {"kim" : {}, "peter" : {{"2008" : "book3"}, {"2009" : "book4"}}} }
```

Comment: dict2 is not a valid dictionary: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725060/adding-dictionaries-recursively-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you migth need `list` as value in `dict2`.

I tried using this

```
>>> dict1 = {"good authors": {"john" : {}, "jack" : {}}, "average authors" : {"kim" : {}, "peter" : {}} }

>>> dict2 = {"john" : [{"2008" : "book1"}, {"2009" : "book2"}], "peter" : [{"2008" : "book3"}, {"2009" : "book4"}]}
>>> for key, value in dict1.items():
...     for dict2key, dict2value in dict2.items():
...         if dict2key in value:
...             value[dict2key] = dict2value
...
>>> dict2
{'john': [{'2008': 'book1'}, {'2009': 'book2'}], 'peter': [{'2008': 'book3'}, {'2009': 'book4'}]}
```

may this help